# $\mid$ in simply typed lambda calculus

Tags: logic, computability, lambda-calculus

> $e = x \mid \lambda x\!:\!\tau.e \mid e \, e \mid c$

So, what is $\mid$ in this example of simply typed lambda calculus?

> The syntax of the simply typed lambda calculus is essentially that of
>   the lambda calculus itself. (Wikipedia, simply typed lambda calculus)

I wasn't able to see $\mid$ in untyped lambda calculus.. How is $\mid$ used in lambda calculus?

Comment: Where did you come across this?

Comment: If I interpret your question correctly, the $\mid$ simply means an alternative in the syntax: an expression $e$ is either a variable ($x$), a $\lambda$ term ($\lambda x: \tau. e$), a function application ($ee$) or a constant ($c$). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form.

Comment: @JohannesKloos Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered list](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading on the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 4):

If I interpret your question correctly, the ∣ simply means an alternative in the syntax: an expression e is either a variable (x), a λ term (λx:τ.e), a function application (ee) or a constant (c)